# Laravel: Handling concurrent webhooks with same timestamp

Tags: laravel, webhooks, razorpay

We are using Razorpay Payouts API in one of our Laravel projects.
Razorpay's servers send us a webhook callback everytime a payout's status gets updated. Whenever a webhook callback is received for failed payments, we issue refund to the users.
The problem is, in some cases, we receive multiple callbacks with same payload and at the same timestamp. Due to this, our system issues refunds multiple times to users.
What's the proper way to handle concurrent callbacks?

Right now we are using `DB Transactions` but this doesn't seem to solve the issue.